# Ask the user to type in the text file name that's going to be created

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, filewriter

I have the code to create a text file when he presses "Generate report" button but it only generates the text file as pre-determined name "Report.txt". My desired functionality is that when the user presses "Generate report" button, a small window should ask the user to type in the file name(perhaps use JOptionPane?) and press Ok accordingly.

```
else if (str.equals("Generate Report")) {

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Report.txt");  //instead of report.txt, I want to user to type in the name
        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        String title="Title: "+lb1.getText();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        buffer.write(title);
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("\nDate and Time of Creation: "+dateFormat.format(date));

        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("\nList of activities & their duration:"); 
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.newLine();
        buffer.write("List of all paths with the activity names and total duration:");
        buffer.newLine();

        String txtArea = ta1.getText();
        String[] txtArray = txtArea.split("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < txtArray.length; i++) {
            buffer.write(txtArray[i]);
            buffer.newLine();
        }

        buffer.close();
        ta1.setText("Report Generated");

        buffer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only create the `FileWriter` as the user pressed the `Generate report` button. Then the target file name should already be set and can be used in the constructor of `FileWriter`.

Comment: I don't understand how the code you included is relevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the user a save dialog like he wants to have it. With just some demonstration code on top.

```
package save;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FileSave {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("someframe");
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        Optional<File> fileLocation = new FileSave().showSaveDialog(jFrame);
        if (fileLocation.isPresent()) {
            File saveLocation = fileLocation.get();
            System.out.println(saveLocation);
            // TODO your save logic goes here.
        }

    }

    public Optional<File> showSaveDialog(JFrame frame) {

        String property = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File userHome = new File(property);
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(userHome);
        chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
        chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(userHome, "Report.txt"));

        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return Optional.of(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`JOptionPane` is probably the easiest solution.

```
else if(str.equals("Generate Report"))
{

        try {
            String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a filename");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
            ...
```

If you want to save the file at a specific location and give it a specific extension you can specify those in the constructor of the `FileWriter` i.e.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\" + filename +".txt")
```

Comment: And how do I make it store in the D drive like initially my code was?

Comment: And this is not a text file! How do I make it a text file?

Comment: This is real crap. JOptionPane is not dedicated for saving files. `JFileDialog` is dedicated for saving or opening files, shows the existing files etc.

Comment: @Ayaan, it's not clear from your question that the file must be stored on the D drive (and it's a kind of silly requirement).

Comment: Also if you use this approach on Linux it wont work because D:\\ is just the beginning of a file name.

Comment: @michaeak, the request is for the user to type in the filename so it's the question that is crap not the answer.

Comment: The original question does not contain D:\ at all. The question can be improved, nonetheless your answer does not lead to a standard user interface.

Comment: @michaeak, it's not my answer. You should take the time to read through any text properly before replying and being more constructive than calling other peoples efforts for crap.

Comment: ok, I should have written `the answer` instead of `your answer` - sorry for that

Comment: In this context seeing JOptionPane is enough to see the author of the answer did not bring the best possible or the easiest approach. The code is not even dealing with an abortion of the user. So sorry for the rude words, but even finding nice words does not make the answer any better.